# How to fix " examining the file 'C:\User\Appdata\Microsoft\VisualStudio\110.0\ActivityLog.xml' " error?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

When the start project on VS 2012 I get this error and I arrived this path there is no AppData file and also Activitylog.xml

[image]

I tried some way for fixing this error but there are not working.

I tried this methods:

[**Data-Tier App Repeair**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/06/07/upgrade-issue-to-visual-studio-2012-rc.aspx)

[**devenv.exe way in fourth answer by eryang**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/535eff23-fb40-40a6-960b-29c91e9145dc/visual-studio-has-encountered-an-exception-this-may-be-caused-by-an-extension?forum=vsdebug)

Any idea for this problem ? Thank  for your answers

Comment: have you tried disabling extensions one at a time to figure out which one is causing the issue?

Comment: What kind of extension for example?

Comment: The error message suggests that it could be caused by an extension. Goto tools/Extensions. and disabled one by one or all and reenable one by one to see if one if them is the cause

Comment: Thanks for advice. I fixed it. The source of problem "Web Essential 2012" extension.